# Rookie Python-questions

Tags: python, ftp

Is it possible to make python run on your homepage? I know, this is a really stupid question but please don't pick on me for my stupidity :)

If it is possible, how? Do you have to upload/install the executing part of Python to you website using FTP? or...?

Edit: Just found out my provider does not support python and that shell access is completely restricted. Problem solved :)

Comment: You want to host a Python script on a webpage?  Something like http://www.trypython.org/ ?

Comment: "python run on your homepage".  Cannot parse this.  Can you write anything more to explain what these five words might mean?

Comment: What I meant was that I was not sure if Python could be run in a browser. I don't know if this explains my problem a little better? But anyways, I have found out, that I've chosen a stupid hosting provider and they don't support it :)

Comment: @Latze: Your browser -- and it's ability to run Python -- has nothing to do with your web server.  The server and the browser are completely separate and unrelated.  What are you talking about?  Please update your question to explain your use case in **detail**.

Comment: I am sorry if I have not explained myself clearly to you :) The question was written in kind of a hurry and the first responsed showed that I had posted the question with insufficient knowledge about this topic. I will consider reading a little more about what, I am asking for and I will take more time to write the question to avoid stupid interpretation-problems (like the browser-one - what I meant was actually if it was possible to "host a python script on a webpage").

Comment: @Latze: If this is **not** your real question, then please close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything depends on the hosting provider you use for your homepage -- do they offer Python among their services, and, if so, what version, and how do you write server-side scripts to use it (is it CGI-only, or...?) -- if not, or the version / deployment options disappoint, what do they allow in terms of giving you shell access and running long-time processes?

It's impossible for us to judge any of these aspects, because every single one of them depends on your hosting provider, and absolutely none of them depends on Python itself!-)

Comment: Wow... So many aspects of this I've completely missed :) Good response, bud!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I don't know exactly how but I know it is possible. Mabye look into this website:

https://trinket.io/

This website lets you do this. I sent them a message to see how they do it so I will update this to let you know after they respond.

Comment: It is not useful to answer with "I don't know how, but I know it is possible". The question specifically asked for the "how". You should first look up the solution (if it exists) and then post it. In this case there is even not a hurry as the question is 7 years old, and already has an accepted answer. So better take your time to get the info and then post, instead of posting this.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a scripting language, though it is used gracefully for building back end web applications.